# Android navigation drawer shadow on inside

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is there a quick way to render the shadow that the navigation drawer creates on the inside of the draw, rather than over the main content?  Kinda to make it look like the drawer is under the main content, rather than over.

I thought there might be an easy way to do it using `setDrawerShadow()` but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) or  Implementing a custom sliding menu.